# How to store different (random & temp) backend data for each user, without login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-users

What's the simplest way to persist small backend data for each user?

I'm working on a program that will make a random choice for each user, a single-word string, and I'm just starting to decide how to architect it. Although the choices are random, I want them to be persistent — not necessarily if the user comes back the next day, but at least through a session that could be 20 minutes. This would be totally trivial on the front-end, but the random choice must occur on the Node backend (because the user can't know what it is), and can't change when they make their next request. For these purposes, we're assuming a user technically literate enough to view source or open dev tools, but not concerned about someone hacking in.

I already know how to store data in a database (Mongo or SQL), but this seems like overkill for a single word. I already know how to log in users, with user/password or with OAuth, but this again seems like overkill because the data isn't really private and shouldn't require logins. Also, that's extra trouble for the user. I'm considering using Firebase to authenticate anonymous users, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler/faster way for my backend to identify which low-security user I'm dealing with, just to interact with one word for the first user, and a different word for a second user.

Should I go with Firebase anonymous user login? Is there something simple I didn't think of? Thank you!

Comment: Anything related to user's [`session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Comment: The first that comes to my mind is a PRNG, seeded with the users sessionID. Therefore the sequence of "random" choices can be reproduced. And no need to store anything.

Comment: A simple session is all you need. Set a cookie with a random, unique session id, store data somewhere, anywhere, even in memory, on your backend and associate it with that session id. Done.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I knew I was looking for something really simple, but blanking on my own. I ended up using express-session, setting a sessionID and storing some basic info on the backend using sessionID as key. It deletes anything that hasn't been used in an hour. Much better than authenticating anonymous users, since there's such a limited lifespan to save.

Comment: “Authenticating anonymous users” is an oxymoron to begin with.

Comment: @deceze Technically/literally, perhaps, but it's an actual thing you can do as a developer. You don't ask your user for any credentials, so you don't really know who your user is, but you still keep track of when the same user returns, and store info about them. They're probably using hardware IDs or something like that in the background, but I haven't looked into the details behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header. For example, if you're using the node 'http' module:

```
var http = require('http')
var cookie = require('cookie') // npm install if you need to

// Server set up code
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    //Gets called on each http request to your server

    var randomString = yourRandomStringGenerator();
    var cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie);
    if (cookies.myCookie) {
        // already there, do nothing
    } else {
        response.setHeader('Set-Cookie',`myCookie=${randomString}`)
    }
    // Your other server routing etc.
}
```

This header also accepts a `Max-Age` and `Expires` parameter if you'd like them to last beyond a single session, but if `Expires` is not set then the cookie is automattically a session cookie. See documentation on `Set-Cookie` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)